# how to validate ID or passport image before upload in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, image-upload

how can I restrict user to just upload their ID or Passport images instead of uploading other own images or any other dummy image in laravel

searching for AI or anything which help to analyze image before upload any help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i complete this process
install Tesseract in your system in (windows, Linux, etc)
then install any OCR i used following
https://github.com/alimranahmed/LaraOCR
follow instructions
if you found empty response restart your system or wait Tesseract to get addressed(in my case i face this)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).